# Unknown modifier in pregmatch

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

We recently transferred our hosting and all of the sudden errors came up to our preg_match scripts.

```
$lines = explode("\n",$email); //Email message by email forwarding    

if(preg_match("/^(.*)/ GMT(.*)/       <reply@pipe.mydomain.com>:/",$lines[$i],$matches)){
                    $message .= str_replace($matches[1],"",$lines[$i]);
                }
```

It returns unknown modifier 'G' after removing G, it shows unknown modifier 'M' error.

Also tried preg_match_all() still same error shows up.

Comment: don't you need to escape `/` in the pattern??

Comment: Your error settings are probably different on the new server as well, you should adjust if this is production that so you aren't exposing credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EScape the middle forward slashes or use different php delimiters.

```
"~^(.*)/ GMT(.*)/       <reply@pipe.mydomain.com>:~"
```

Use `\h+` to match one or more horizontal spaces.

```
"~^(.*)/\h+GMT(.*)/\h+<reply@pipe.mydomain.com>:~"
```